# Object references in Java - Linked Lists

Tags: java

I was under the impression that creating a variable and setting it equal to an object would act as a reference, ie. changing the original object would subsequently "change" the variable as well. The code i'm specifically referring to is as follows:

```
public class ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode next;
      ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
   }
...
ListNode l1 = ... // l1 is an input
ListNode iterator = head; // copying l1 into a new list, starting with 'head'
...
iterator.next = l1;
l1 = l1.next;
```

The last piece of code loops multiple times. Why is it that, when we set `iterator.next = l1`, it acts as copying the 'l1' object, instead of creating a reference to l1? Shouldn't the result just be a bunch of copies of l1, rather than at each step of the way?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're referring to pointers. When you create a new pointer to an existing object, it doesn't update the original object's pointer.

For example:

```
ListNode l1 = ...
ListNode iterator = ...

iterator.next = l1
```

In this case, `iterator.next` points to the same object that `l1` points to. If I then change the pointer `l1` using the following line:

```
l1 = l1.next
```

`l1` is changed here, meaning the pointer, not the object. I can create as many pointers as I want to the same object:

```
Object a = ...
Object b = a
Object c = a
Object d = a
```

All of these pointers (a, b, c, d) point to the same object, and I can use them interchangeably, but if I change one of the pointers to point to a different object:

```
b = new Object();
```

b no longer points to the same object, but that does not change a, c, or d. Those all point to the same original object.

Comment: Gotcha. So if 'l1' were instead to be declared as an object, say as ```l1 = new ListNode(...)```, then 'iterator' would change with ```l1 = l1.next```, correct?

Comment: `l1 = l1.next` will change `l1` to point to whatever object was stored in `l1.next`. It will not change `iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can also be referred to for removing an element from a linked list.

As stated by @David so far, `iterator.next` points to the object that `l1` points to and `l1 = l1.next` the pointer `l1` changes. This simply means `iterator.next` will now points to what `l1.next` points to.

Since our `ListNode` is unidirectional, starting from `iterator` (as the head of the list and assuming it's not null), we can no longer access the object referenced by `l1` since `iterator.next` points to `l1.next`.

Since we cannot navigate backward, we can no longer access what `l1` points to.

And in that case we can consider that the object referenced by `l1` has been removed from the list that starts with `iterator` as the head of the list.